# Implementing a blog excerpt in custom theme

Tags: excerpt

I'm trying to make my blog posts show an excerpt but can't seem to do it manually. [My blog site is here](http://averylawoffice.ca/blog).

I've gotten this snippet from the wordpress.org site

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

and it tells me to replace the

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

with it. However I can't just replace it my index.php file as then it excerpts everything. (Maybe because of how my index.php file is set up?)

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file.
 */

get_header(); ?>

        <div id="main">


                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>


                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

                <?php if (function_exists("pagination")) {
                    pagination($additional_loop->max_num_pages);
                } ?>


        </div><!-- #main -->


<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I've tried to replace the have_posts() and then replace the second line of code and then even alter this lines:

and I get my excerpt under my post in my post but then it makes my website REALLY slow.

For some reason my choices for only showing summary in Settings > Review don't apply so I'm having to do it manually.

Any help is appreciated as to how I can customize this excerpt code to work with my blog.

### UPDATED

As Linnea suggested I have updated the content-page.php page to this:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template used for displaying separate posts on blog page.
 *
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <span class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="blog entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <h2 class="blog entry-subtitle">Posted on: <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></h2>
    </span><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'toolbox' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
        <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'toolbox' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>


    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

Where the `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` is now used to be `<?php the_content('<br/><br/>CONTINUE READING...'); ?>` however there is no change to my blog entries on my blog. Maybe there is another area I should be looking?

Comment: What does you content-page.php code looks like will paste that code as well to see.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Maqk. I've updated my question with that code.

Comment: try looking for a `home.php` instead of `index.php` and if it uses a different template part.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion majick. I have no home.php file in my custom theme. Is that bad?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your index.php file calls the content-page.php file.

The code you are looking to change is probably in the content-page.php file.  The key is this line:

```
get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );
```

It is directing WordPress to load content-page.php

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply Linnea! I've updated my question with my findings. It's still not working however I have a feeling we're close! Do you know why it might not be working still?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if ( has_excerpt() && !is_single() ) {
    the_excerpt();
    echo '<a class="more-link" href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) .'">'. __("Continue reading","textdomain") .'</a>';
}else{
    the_content( __( 'Continue reading', 'textdomain' ) );

    wp_link_pages( array(
        'before'      => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __( 'Pages:', 'textdomain' ) . '</span>',
        'after'       => '</div>',
        'link_before' => '<span>',
        'link_after'  => '</span>',
    ));
} ?>
```

I Hope this should work for you.